# Setting window icon in Avalonia

Tags: xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am writing a small app for as a school project and I cannot figure out how can I change the window icon. I found the "Icon" property of Window, but I have no clue how it works, as I have found little documentation on it. When I tried to input something in the field, it threw an error, that the resource could not be found. I read something on importing resources as well, but this is my first app of this kind, so I am completely lost. Any help much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add your icon as `AvaloniaResource`. If you are using MVVM template, everything in `Assets` directory should be added as one. If you aren't, then add

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to your .csproj file.
Then put your icon into Assets directory.
After that simply writing `Icon="/Assets/your-icon.ico"` in your window xaml should work.

Answer (score 5):

This was more what I was looking for, in setting the icon in c#.

```cs
IBitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(AvaloniaLocator.Current?.GetService<IAssetLoader>()?.Open(
     new Uri($"avares://{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}/Assets/example.png"))
);
var exampleWindow = new Window()
{
Title = "Example",
Height = 700,
Icon = new WindowIcon(bitmap)
}
```

in axaml

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
 Icon="/Assets/example.png"> 
...
</Window>
```